# Is the "square-free locus" of a holomorphic function open?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a complex manifold and $p \in M$ be a point.
It is well-known that the stalk $\mathcal{O}_p=\mathcal{O}_{M,p}$ of the sheaf of holomorphic function on M at $p$ is a unique factorization domain (UFD). So we can consider the condition that the germ of a holomorphic function is irreducible or square-free.

**My Question**

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function defined on an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$, then is the  "square-free locus" of $f$

$V=\{q \in U \mid f_q$ is square-free as an element of $\mathcal{O}_q \}$

open?

**Remark**

There is a counterexample for a similar question for "irreducible locus" $W=\{q \in U \mid f_q$ is irreduclibe as an element of $\mathcal{O}_q \}$.

(A holomorphic function $x^2-yz^2$ on $\mathbb{C}^3$ is irreducible at $(0,0,0)$ but NOT at $(0,b,0)$ for non-zero $b$.)